# Lua char spacing perfectly

Tags: lua

Failed Spacing

[image: 1]

I'm trying to get all of these names with a max char of 31 to line up all together in the same row by adding the number of spaces per player name that it needs. I've been trying to accomplish this for some time now and I just can't figure this out completely.

This is my current code which is a disaster I know..

```
local c = client.GetPlayerNameByIndex(i)
if c ~= nil and client.GetPlayerNameByIndex(i) ~= "nil" then
    playerlist[i] = all_trim(client.GetPlayerNameByIndex(i))

    local leve = 67
    local namelength = #client.GetPlayerNameByIndex(i) --max 31 chars
    local output = "" .. client.GetPlayerNameByIndex(i)
    local newspace = ""
    local neededspaces = 31 - #client.GetPlayerNameByIndex(i)
    print(neededspaces)
    for i=1, 31-#string.sub(client.GetPlayerNameByIndex(i), 1, 31) do
        newspace = newspace .. "　"
    end
    playerinfolist[i] = output .. newspace .. "a"


end
```

In simple terms I want all of the "a"s to line up with each string. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: It's a non-monospaced font.  Width of each character is different.  Try inserting `"\t"` tab character instead of spaces.

Comment: \t works as plain text but however I'm not sure I'm adding the right amount? Because everything is still unaligned or the code is just incorrect?

Comment: like egor said, it is the font. think wllw vs `wllw`

Comment: I'd try to solve this in the GUI. print the text in two columns

Comment: You can also swap two columns.